# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable ; while creating a graph

Tags: plotly, visualization, scatter-plot, figure

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.scatter(x=stud,y=maths,name="Maths marks",line= dict(color='blue',width = 4)))

fig.add_trace(go.scatter(x = stud, y = science, name = "Science marks", line = dict(color='red',width = 4)))

fig.add_trace(go.scatter(x = stud ,y = programing, name = "Programing marks", line = dict(color='green',width = 4,dash='dash')))

fig.add_trace(go.scatter(x = stud ,y = database_subject, name = "Database marks", line = dict(color='firebrick',width = 4,dash='dot')))


fig.update_layout(title="Students Marks", xaxis_title="Students", yaxis_title="Marks")

fig.show()
```

This throws the following `TypeError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-142e63ca6574> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 fig = go.Figure()
      2 
----> 3 fig.add_trace(go.scatter(x=stud,y=maths,name="Maths marks",line= dict(color='blue',width = 4)))
      4 
      5 fig.add_trace(go.scatter(x = stud, y = science, name = "Science marks", line = dict(color='red',width = 4)))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

why i am getting this error?

Comment: this question may end up closed because it's due a typo, but this is a common typo people make when using `plotly` because plotly express objects use a lowercase syntax and plotly graph objects use an upper case: you have `px.scatter` and `go.Scatter`

Answer (score 1):

You need to capitalize `scatter` in `go.Scatter`:

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=stud,y=maths,name="Maths marks",line= dict(color='blue',width = 4)))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = stud, y = science, name = "Science marks", line = dict(color='red',width = 4)))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = stud ,y = programing, name = "Programing marks", line = dict(color='green',width = 4,dash='dash')))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = stud ,y = database_subject, name = "Database marks", line = dict(color='firebrick',width = 4,dash='dot')))


fig.update_layout(title="Students Marks", xaxis_title="Students", yaxis_title="Marks")

fig.show()
```